# IF statement within FOR loop statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

I want to put if statements within my for loop checking parameters but I don't know how to do it, I want this so I don't have to duplicate my code and make it huge, redundant and messy.

This is what I am trying to do

```
for( int i = elevator1CurrentStatus.floorNumber; if(boundary == 9) i<boundary else i>boundary ;i+=i+countDirection){

//Code Here 

}
```

How would I implement this? Basically I want the test statement stating whether to count up or down to depend on a variable and select which direction based on that variable. Count direction is implemented earlier and is either +1 or -1.
    for( int i = elevator1CurrentStatus.floorNumber; (if(boundary == 9) iboundary;) ;i+=i+countDirection)

```
 for( int i = elevator1CurrentStatus.floorNumber; (if(boundary == 9) i<boundary else i>boundary) ;i+=i+countDirection)
```

Comment: Can you explain your IF clause? What are you trying to do in `if(boundary == 9) i<boundary else i>boundary`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use ternary operator:

```
for(int i = elevator1CurrentStatus.floorNumber; 
    boundary == 9 ? i < boundary : i > boundary; 
    i += i + countDirection) {

//Code Here 

}
```

But I would move the condition to separate function/method to improve readability.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, thanks! I'll accept this as the answer when it lets me

Comment: YOu might want to add a few brackets here and there - to improve readability. `(boundary == 9) ? (i < boundary): (i > boundary);`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to put the condition in a separate function. It will make it more readable. Try not to inline complex conditions. Also, you can now use any multi-level if-else, switch case or any other operation that returns a boolean.

Here is what you can do:

```
bool conditionCheck(int i, int boundary) {
        if (boundary == 9) {
            return i < boundary;
        } else {
            return i > boundary;
        }
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int boundary = 10;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; conditionCheck(i, boundary); i++) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Invalid syntax. The question is about C++. YOur code is not C++.

Comment: @SigTerm Is it ok now :D

Comment: Nope. Still not C++. Grab a C++ compiler, try to compile it, see what happens.

Comment: @SigTerm Thanks. I was just doing that and by the time I came back it was already corrected. I am going to kill myself of shame now :(